# UWP/C#: ObservableCollection sort in-place (w/o scrolling)

Tags: c#, sorting, uwp, observablecollection

In an UWP app I'm trying to sort an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to a `ListView` - therefore `collection.OrderBy(..)` (which creates a new collection) is not an option.

Until now I used this extension-method:

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this 
ObservableCollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
    source.Clear();
    foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
    {
        source.Add(sortedItem);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this way the current 'scrolling-offset' is resetted due to  `source.Clear()` and the corresponding `ListView` scrolls all the way back to the top - which is pretty bad user-experience.

Any ideas?

Comment: am not familiar with what you are asking shall i ask you something have tried to save "scrolling-offset" in an object before source.Clear() and reset that value again, which might help.

Comment: That would be my 'last resort'. It would probably work, but with source.Clear() the list would scroll to the top at first and then shortly after that reset to the stored 'scrolling-offset'. That would look odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can try is to create a *temp* collection that contains all the items from your original collection, sort it, then loop through its items and only re-order the ones of which position needs to be updated. Something like this -

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var sortedSource = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedSource.Count; i++)
    {
        var itemToSort = sortedSource[i];

        // If the item is already at the right position, leave it and continue.
        if (source.IndexOf(itemToSort) == i)
        {
            continue;
        }

        source.Remove(itemToSort);
        source.Insert(i, itemToSort);
    }
}
```

Also, you will want the `ListView` to keep the scroll offset when items are animating. This can be done by setting -

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I found this UX related question really interesting and I even ended up creating a little [demo project](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/ListViewSortingRepo) for it. :) The *gif* below demostrates the end result. To me it provides a better experience as I know visually, what items are or aren't repositioned by the sorting.

[image: ListView sorting animation]

Comment: Instead of source.Remove and Insert, you could call the .`Move` exposed by observables. It internally does the same though. One thing to remember is calling Move will trigger collection changed events which might or might not be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem a while ago and I ended up with this:

```
Func<TempoMarking, IComparable> selectorGetter = null;
// Setting the selectorGetter here
for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Collection.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        YourType currentItem = Collection[j];

        if (selectorGetter(currentItem).CompareTo(selectorGetter(Collection[j + 1])) == 1)
        {
            Collection.Remove(currentItem);
            Collection.Insert(j + 1, currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably not the best solution and it lags a bit on phones such as L640 but it works. If you need to scroll to some item in your `ListView` you may use this method:

```
YourListView.ScrollIntoView(ListViewItemToScrollTo);
```