# UWP C# Sorting Items in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, sorting, uwp, scrollviewer, windows-iot-core-10

I have added a few items in my `scrollviewer`.
However, the items are not added in sequence. After adding them i would like to sort them in ascending order. 
I have checked out this [thread - UWP/C#: ObservableCollection sort in-place (w/o scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303000/uwp-c-observablecollection-sort-in-place-w-o-scrolling), but the way it worked on a `listview` doesn't work for me. Is there any way to implement it to my favor?

Thank you.

[image]

I created a `UserControl` to be added when the `Add` button is clicked, edited and saved.

```
<TextBlock Text="Card" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
<TextBlock x:Name="CardAddress" Text="-" FontSize="10" Height="30" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,18,0,0" />
<TextBlock x:Name="ZoneNameA" Text="Zone A" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="ZoneNameB" Text="Zone B" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="ZoneNameC" Text="Zone C" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="ZoneNameD" Text="Zone D" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="320,0,0,0"/>

<AppBarButton x:Name="EditZoneName" Icon="Edit" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Visible" Click="EditZoneName_Click"/>
<AppBarButton x:Name="DeleteZoneName" Icon="Delete" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="DeleteZoneName_Click"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
internal void setZoneName(string zoneA, string zoneB, string zoneC, string zoneD, string cardaddress)
{
    if (cardaddress.Equals("")) cardaddress = "1";
    if (zoneA.Equals("")) zoneA = "Zone A";
    if (zoneB.Equals("")) zoneB = "Zone B";
    if (zoneC.Equals("")) zoneC = "Zone C";
    if (zoneD.Equals("")) zoneD = "Zone D";
    zone.setZoneName(zoneA, zoneB, zoneC, zoneD, cardaddress);
    updateDisplay();
}
internal void updateDisplay()
{
    CardAddress.Text = zone.cardAddress;
    ZoneNameA.Text = zone.ZoneAlabel;
    ZoneNameB.Text = zone.ZoneBlabel;
    ZoneNameC.Text = zone.ZoneClabel;
    ZoneNameD.Text = zone.ZoneDlabel;
}
```

When I click `Add` and 'Save' the details would like to find out how to `sort` the items in ascending order.

```
private void AddZoneCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ZonesUserControl zoneControl = new ZonesUserControl(this, new Zone());
    Zone24_Panel.Children.Add(zoneControl);

    ZoneNameUserControl zoneName = new ZoneNameUserControl(this, new Zone());
    ZoneName_Panel.Children.Add(zoneName);
}  


private async void SaveZoneCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    zoneSaved = true;
    editZoneName = false;
    foreach (ZoneNameUserControl u in ZoneName_Panel.Children)
    {
        if (u.currentState == ZoneNameUserControl.State.EDIT)
        {
            u.currentState = ZoneNameUserControl.State.IDLE;
            var zoneAname = ZoneAName.Text;
            var zoneBname = ZoneBName.Text;
            var zoneCname = ZoneCName.Text;
            var zoneDname = ZoneDName.Text;
            var cardadr = CardAddress.Text;
            u.setZoneName(zoneAname, zoneBname, zoneCname, zoneDname, cardadr);
        }

        //u.updateDisplayName();
        await saveZoneNameToJSON(getZoneName());
    }

    foreach (ZonesUserControl u in Zone24_Panel.Children)
    {
        u.updateZoneLabel();
    }

    CardAddress.IsEnabled = false;
    ZoneAName.IsEnabled = false;
    ZoneBName.IsEnabled = false;
    ZoneCName.IsEnabled = false;
    ZoneDName.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Kudos on the excellent/more than well formed and informing question!

Answer (score 0):

The best and most functional solution would be to rewrite the code not to use direct control manipulation but to use a `ListView` or other list control and utilize `DataTemplate` instead. This has an incredible number of benefits, including virtualization, consistency, better maintainability and better performance overall. Please, check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview) for more details on how to implement these controls including data-binding.

If you insist on manual control creation, then it is still possible, but not very convenient. First, you should expose the property you want to sort by in the custom control code-behind. Suppose you want to sort by some `Number` property:

```
public int Number { get; private set; }
```

Initialize the property from the constructor or from the custom control code. Then, to sort, you will need to actually detach the controls from the visual tree and re-attach them in sorted order (or alternatively move them around using the `Move` method, but that would likely result in unnecessarily complicated code).

```
var controls = Container.Children.OfType<CustomControl>().OrderBy(c=>c.Number).ToArray();
Container.Children.Clear();
foreach (var control in controls)
{
    Container.Children.Add(control);
}
```

Where the `Container` is the panel type where the controls are stored as children and `CustomControl` is the type of your custom control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The issue of me using manual control is that I do not know how many "CARD" i need to add ultimately. I may need to "ADD" and also "DELETE" the cards based on situation and at the same time to "EDIT" the "ZONE" names.
If I were to rewrite in 'listview' is it possible to accommodate my requirement?
thank you.

Comment: I think it should still be doable using a ListView - you can even embed a custom control in the ListView DataTemplate, so it should not be limiting. To accommodate for the buttons inside the item rows (edit button, etc.), you can also use data binding with commands (`ICommand`). I am not saying you have to rewrite your code, it should still work with the alternative solution I provided, but I believe using the ListView could make your code more maintainable in the long run :-). It will probably be the only manageable solution if you expect to have a lot of entries, then the virtualization is k

Comment: Hi.. I tried to figure out how to modify my code using `scrollviewer` to `listview` but it became a mess. As I use `usercontrol` to display individual items from a `json` list. Could you please point me some directions which I can implement the `listview` to my solution?

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials on building a `ListView` with custom `DataTemplate`. You could start in official docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#binding-to-a-collection-of-items . As you want to have buttons within the items, you will either need to use relative binding (http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=378) or create a `ICommand` property in the list items themselves, so you can bind to them directly.